# Connect to MySQL DB tunneling with SSH using Emma

Tags: ssh, mysql, connection

I have tried using the `mysql-workbench` but it was too confusing, then I decided to use `emma` instead. I am trying to connect to my MySQL DB through SSH, but I don't see that option when I try to make a new connection. Any suggestions? Thanks!

( *I did try some researching but I could not find helpful results* )

Answer (score 4):

You can create an SSH tunnel manually with:

```
ssh -L 33060:localhost:3306 user@remotehost
```

While this ssh session is open, connections to your port 33060 will be forwarded to (the standard mysql server) port 3306 on the remote server.

Then any mysql client can connect to the mysql server running on 'remotehost', e.g.:

```
mysql -P 33060 -h 127.0.0.1 -u mysqluser -p
```

I've used this method to connect emma to a mysql server running privately (not accessible externally) on another machine before. Unfortunately, with this method, you have to establish the tunnel manually before emma's stored server connection will work.

Answer (score -1):

A much more reliable way to create an ssh tunnel to a remote mysql database is to use gstm, the Gnome SSH Tunnel Manager...

```
sudo apt-get install gstm
```

Then run the gui application, create a named config for your connection, with **host** set to destination host and **port** set to 22 (probably) as the ssh port. Tick **autostart** if you want this tunnel to auto-launch on start up. Then add a port redirect, **type** local, **port** 33060, **host** same as destination, **to port** 3306.

One thing to note is that in clients, php config etc, you will probably want to use `127.0.0.1:33060` rather than `localhost:3306` because reasons. *(Something to do with sockets)*.

Comment: Using a GUI is no more reliable than using console.

Comment: I don't remember why I wrote 'more reliable' any more. I *think* at the time I had problems with having to redo the command line version, whereas the gui version happened once per session. Maybe that has changed. I'm not currently using Ubuntu or doing this tunneling any more, so can't answer definitively. Should I remove the 'more reliable' wording or just delete this answer?